# Get data from csv and calculate average

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

At first I need to calculate average value of a column from csv file using python spark,

I have a code:

```
 scSpark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example: Reading CSV file without mentioning schema") \
.config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
.getOrCreate()

sdfData = scSpark.read.csv("document.csv", header=True, sep=",")
sdfData.show()
```

Then I'm getting next data on the screen:

```
   +---------+------+---------+------------------+
   |     Name| total| test val|             ratio|
   +---------+------+---------+------------------+
   |parimatch|     3|   test7 |0.6164045285312666|
   |parimatch|     4|   test6 |0.5829715240832467|
   |     leon|     3|   test5 |0.6164045285312666|
   |     leon|     4|   test4 |0.5829715240832467|
   |parimatch|     3|   test3 |0.6164045285312666|
   |parimatch|     4|    test |0.5829715240832467|
   +---------+------+---------+------------------+
```

How can I calculate the average between ratio via spark?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Spark have an average function to do this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

average = sdfData.agg(avg(col("ratio")))
```